# Gatsby Starter Blog low Performance

Tags: gatsby, blogs

I did the quick start of this: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog
And I ran a Chrome Audit, but the performance came out at 2%. I made absolutely no changes, just installation. The creator claims to have a good performance.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you run this against the development server, or against the built, static copy? What were the more detailed results? "2% performance" means fairly little.

Comment: I run with local machine

Comment: You must run it in build mode to have a public folder exactly as it will be in the deployment server.

Answer (score 1):

Run in build mode. Run these queries and then test it.

```
gatsby build
gatsby serve
```

Comment: Should be a much higher performance with the build and also try to test it inside the private tab (react dev tools chrome plugin lowers performance)